Melee Opportunist--making opportunity attacks have some bite for melee characters
Opportunity attacks seem great. "Free" damage for someone moving away? Allowing "tanky" characters to punish people running by them? Making it more dangerous for ranged characters to allow melee next to them? Great. And for monsters, that actually (to some degree) works. No one wants a giant to get an OA on you.
But for the tanky PCs...it kinda doesn't work very well unless you have an additional source of per-hit damage (like Divine Smite). Oooh scary, Mr Sword and Board guy will hit me with his 1d8 + 5 damage. Oooh. I'm frightened.
I'm contemplating ways of letting people do this better. Sure, Sentinel is great. It covers the control niche pretty well--the target ain't going no where. But I want to cover the punishment niche. Hence the following (proposed) feat.

Melee Opportunist
You gain the following benefits:

Enemies provoke Opportunity Attacks from you when they move within your reach or make attacks against creatures other than you in addition to the normal triggers.
You can make Opportunity Attacks without expending your reaction, but no more than one on any turn.
When you hit with an Opportunity Attack, the target takes additional damage equal to your proficiency bonus times the number of attacks you can make with the Attack action. This damage is the same damage type as your weapon damage.


Question: Is this within the ballpark for combat-focused D&D 5e (2014) feats (ie strong enough to be worth taking vs something like Sentinel for a "tanky" character but not so strong as to obviate other options)? Are there obvious exploits or combos that would make this problematic?

this is way stronger than the Cavalier capstone, which is extremely powerful.

Limited out-of-turn actions is a guiding principle in 5E, and you broke it
You're beginning to recreate the problems of 4E, where out-of-turn actions quickly became untenably vast, because they broke their original rules and started allowing lots of stuff that should have been once-per-round interrupts or reactions to become anytime free actions. It's a focus hog on two levels; the characters with more opportunities to act out-of-turn end up both the focus of the action more than they should be, and the player has to be watching constantly for anything that triggers their reactions, so they never get a break on their own mental focus.
The fact that the feat also makes many more opportunities for opportunity attacks (moving within or out of range, and into range if combined with Polearm Master, or attacking someone other than you) exacerbates this problem.
And this is before you get into balance issues.
Every melee Rogue wants this, because it's completely broken in conjunction with Sneak Attack
Sneak Attack is limited to once-per-turn. You just gave them a much more reliable way to get out-of-turn sneak attack, and let them do it potentially multiple times per round. No matter how optimized a melee Rogue gets, they can't sneak attack more than twice per round right now; once on their turn, and once on another character's turn using their reaction. With this feat, they can do it a lot.
The bonus damage from the feat is just gravy in this context; a Fighter could eventually get +24 damage per opportunity attack from the feat, but the Rogue's sneak attack is eventually adding an average of +35 damage before the +6 from the feat (total +41), and the sneak attack damage can be doubled on a crit. The damage ratio between the Fighter with this feat and the Rogue is even more in the Rogue's favor at low levels, so this isn't an "only at high levels" problem; the melee Rogue just gets universally better in a way that would be hard to match with any other feat.
Similar problems apply for Paladins, where they are still limited by spell slots, but being able to front load damage instead of spreading it over multiple rounds in a fight constitutes a major advantage (damage done in round one is more valuable than the same damage done in round three, after the enemies have been able to damage you for multiple rounds).
You just gave a capstone class feature and more in a single feat
As Tiger Guy points out in the comments, 5E has violated the principle of only allowing a single reaction per round once. But it was the 18th level capstone feature of the Cavalier, Vigilant Defender:

In combat, you get a special reaction that you can take once on every creature's turn, except your turn. You can use this special reaction only to make an opportunity attack, and you can't use it on the same turn that you take your normal reaction.

That's a slightly weaker version of your second bullet point (which doesn't restrict use of your normal reaction), with no other benefits, as the capstone ability of a class. No feat should be replicating the entirety of a major class feature like this, let alone improving on them.

Thanks. I will note that the standard wording "enemy moves" does restrict to use of the target's own movement/action, so forced movement doesn't count. But yeah.
Question--how would it be if that second bullet point just wasn't there (and it was limited to willing movement)? No multiple OA's per round, no pushing, just more damage on your OAs plus more triggers.

the basic idea here is the same as the Cavalier features, just a bit over-tuned.

"You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction." This rule would still apply. It already prevents moving out of a creature's reach from provoking opportunity attacks and it would continue to do the same for moving while inside of it here. The same way Disengaging would also still prevent these. Regular opportunity attacks make no reference to willing movement, it is only this rule that prevents them.

@Exempt-Medic: K, I forgot the exact wording that blocked this stuff for Opportunity Attacks, and was thinking of all the debates over what triggers Booming Blade's "booming energy" (which already requires "willingly moving" to trigger). It's not quite as bad as I made it out to be I guess, but it's still much better than it has any right to be.

@TigerGuy: Thanks for that. I'd forgotten the Cavalier (which does violate this 5E design principle, but only for [mostly] single-classed 18th level Fighters in a specific subclass, not "anyone with an ASI to blow").

@BenjaminTHall: A feat that dropped bullet point #2 is not so obviously broken. I think it's fine (though the extra damage is a bit over-engineered in a way I'd probably avoid; just double proficiency bonus or something would make it work equally well for any class, not risk overpowering the fighter, though perhaps it's justified by bonus attack damage on other classes), but I think you should ask a new question (I think after a three day turnaround for homebrew review? Someone who knows the rules better can correct me) to get a good answer to a wildly altered version of the feat like that.

@BenjaminTHall: I will note that even without bullet point #2, this does still provide the unusual feature of allowing Rogues more opportunities to sneak attack out-of-turn. Polearm Master lets you attack as people close on you, but none of the weapons it works with are compatible with Sneak Attack (since none of them are finesse weapons). Whether that's a problem, I don't know (enemies don't need to move around the rogue to attack them, and they're probably inclined to attack the rogue anyway, so it's not like Polearm Master, where if it worked for sneak attack, every rogue would want it).
